# Why build and libs folders in Android project can't be commited or pushed?

Tags: android, git, github, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio in combination with GitHub repository. So I have just pushed my entire project but I mentioned that I can push only my src folder. Is there any reason that I can't push my build and src folders or just I'm doing something wrong? When I'm trying to commit them I'm receiving a message telling me that there is no changes detected, but when I go in my repository there is no such folders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default Android Studio puts the `build` directory (both at the project level and the module level) in the `.gitignore`.

This is typically the desired behavior, as there is no reason to keep most of the generated files in version control. Gradle will create these again for you on any machine you download the project to.

If you want to include the build directories, simple remove `/build` from both the `.gitignore` in your project's root and the `.gitignore` in your module's root.

The `libs` directory should not be in there by default, but if you are adding files to that directory and Git isn't recognizing the change, that's where I would look.