# Drawables won't push to github Android Studio

Tags: android, git, github, android-studio, github-for-mac

Hello I am not sure why this is the case, but when I commit and push to GitHub no matter how many png files or pictures I add to my drawable folders, the drawables folder never changes on the repository when I access it thru my profile on GitHub.

Example picture:

[image]

I have done research, but didn't find much substance

[Why build and libs folders in Android project can't be commited or pushed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24372262/why-build-and-libs-folders-in-android-project-cant-be-commited-or-pushed)

I was surprised that there is not a lot written on this. This can be fatal if a user commits a project ending error and needs to recover everything on Github just to find that every drawable or png file will be lost.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It depends on how you add the images to Android Studio. If you drop the images their respective folders without letting AS know via a file explorer then the images will not be added to git and they will appear red in the project explorer. If you copy the images and paste them into their respective folders within the AS project explorer then they should be added to git and show up green as shown below.

[image: Android studio file color example]

If there are files you wish to add to git that aren't added already then just right click on the file in the project explorer and select Git -> Add or use <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+A</kbd>.

Comment: I have a similar problem with AS `v3.1.4`. (now at 2018). With images, I don't even try (because I don't think `git` will be able to deal properly with binary files such as a PNG image); however, the embedded git client in AS doesn't let me `rightclick -> Git -> Add...` any file within `res/drawable` or `res/layout` for some reason. I am aware that the AS Project explorer hides some of the complexity of the folder structure (merging all `drawable*` and `layout*` folder variants into one for usability). Perhaps because of that the Git client in AS doesn't want to commit them or something...

Comment: ...even XML files suffer from this issue. Because of that, I feel tempted to just ignore Android Studio's Git client, go directly to a `terminal` and just use `git` from the commandline like I would normally do... I wonder if the Git integration in AS would have any problem with this...