# Android Studio Bitbucket plugin share project on Bitbucket dont work

Tags: java, android, plugins, android-studio, bitbucket

I have a Problem with my Android Studio and Bitbucket. If I try to Share my Project on Bitbucket it don't work. I enabled VCS, there I can choose "Import into Version Control" -> "Share Project...(with the Bitbucket Icon)" when I click it, its loading and in my Bitbucket account is a new Repository with the name I chose, but there are no files in it. It only generates the new Repository.

Here are pictures what I mean:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1a. download recent [plugin from here](https://bitbucket.org/dmitry_cherkas/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector/downloads) & add it to studio

1b. configure plugin (add ssh keys if u need it / also in bitbucket)

[image]

2. enable vcs in studio (select git)

[image]

3. create repo on bb

[image]

4aaa. get git repo command from bb

[image]

4b. if u dont use ssh keys rename part with "git@..."
 woth your repo addres with https

[image]

5. paste & run this cmd in studio terminal or open terminal in your os(if u had installed git first on windows)

[image]

6. mark files to add to git or make any changes to project 
   (files marked as green will be added to vcs - red not)

[image]

6. commit your changes & push project to git (note that run only cmmmit will not push any file to git remote)

[image]

7. enter creditentials for repo (if u did not done 1b)

[image]

8. u done

[image]

[image]

*edit:*

To add manually(listed on red) files to git commit see:
[via menu or shortcut add](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25900988/4669617)

> For a good sharing of project there is some file to don't add to
>   repository? Or just add all that is present in the projectfolder.
>   AndroidStudioProjects/myproject.... i link all myproject folder?
>   Thanks @ceph3us

**1) files with all sensitive data eg: password, unguarded keys, credentials storages etc.**

**2) any code with value :)**

**as the git repo (server side) is "public" and not guarded and files are not encrypted we are vulnerable to hacking and code/data theft.**

> Thanks, i give you one up vote and can't give another :D .. Anyway, i
>   ask this because i use a private repo for share my project with some
>   friends...and for example the folder release is useless and i can
>   avoid do push it? For other sensitive file there are only ca-app-pubb
>   keys for admob...but the project is in private mode...just for share
>   and branch the develops and make something good :)

to the rescue :) btw see **.gitignore**

example .gitignore

```
/.idea/libraries/
.DS_Store
/.gradle/
/gradle/
/build/
/app/build/
/captures/
.externalNativeBuild
/pl.ceph3us.base.common/tmp/
/aars/release/
!/aars/ln
```

to work "with basic config" we only want:

*.gradle 
 /src (which contains a  java/ (sourcecode)   res/ (resources)) etc
 AndroidManifest.xml

sometimes we neeed:

/lib  (flattered) - but i avoid to push to repo (eventually when we need some specific version)
/jni

all other file are redundant (when u know how to setup "development ide")

see souceset clousure in android gradle plugin "for better understand" what we need to compile/assembly  gradle - android project

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked for me. I am very happy for your help!

Comment: @Maresuke - u welcome I'll be grateful for marking answers as accepted (button in top left corner of my answer under two arrows)

Comment: In step-6 after add origin I'm getting RED then how i can fix this ?

Comment: @kramk - see edit (simplest solution -  use ctrl + alt + a  on a file)

Comment: For a good sharing of project there is some file to don't add to repository?
Or just add all that is present in the projectfolder.
AndroidStudioProjects/myproject.... i link all myproject folder?
Thanks @ceph3us

Comment: Thanks, i give you one up vote and can't give another :D ..
Anyway, i ask this because i use a private repo for share my project with some friends...and for example the folder release is useless and i can avoid do push it? 
For other sensitive file there are only ca-app-pubb keys for admob...but the project is in private mode...just for share and branch the develops and make something good :)